# How to build a windows desktop application to send notification to android device?

Tags: android, windows

How to build a windows desktop application to send a notification to android device?

I prefer using C#.

Is it there any free solution?
I just want to get notification when my ISP assign a new IP address to my home computer.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest to build the `Desktop Application` with `Azure Messaging Services`.

Your `Desktop Application` would then use the `GCM API Key` from your `Google Account` to interact with the Android App using `AMS`.

App will send the content to `AMS`. From there the data would be sent to `GCM`, and then to your `Android Application`.

Start from here -> [LINK](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/services/service-bus/)

Answer (score 1):

It's impossible - for the usage of GCM you need Google service inside client side. Only android device with google service could have it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use azure notification hub, and use the SDK and develop a windows desktop application to send out notifications to apps subscribed to that notification hub. devices could be Android or iOS

Answer (score 0):

Thank for all of you, finally,I am using Google Calendar C# API to create an event in Google Calendar,it fulfill my need in more convenience way.

It works.